# how to find a pattern in file entry, remove leading hash and redirect all entries to file

Tags: sed

Looking for the syntax to find a pattern in a file and remove the leading character from only that pattern.

For example, `find -16` and remove the `#` and save it to file.

Tried `grep 12345-16 testfile2 | sed -e "s/^#//g"` which works but need to capture all entries into the input file.

Example:

From this:

```
something   here 12345-14
something   here 12345-15
# something here 12345-16
```

to this:

```
something   here 12345-14
something   here 12345-15
something   here 12345-16
```

suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with just `sed` alone.

```
sed '/12345-16/s/^# *//' file
```

You can use `-i` option of `sed` to make in-file changes. `/../` in front of `sed` is a regex which only makes changes on lines that has that pattern. All remaining lines will not be touched and be printed out as is.

You don't need `g` for `global` here since you are only removing the leading `#`. I have added a pattern of `^# *` which means `#` **or** `#` followed by `spaces` at the start of the line. You can create your own pattern based on the structure of your file.

Comment: @user3369123 You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question complete by clicking on the check mark next to it.